# Why can 'int' be treated as 'ushort' but not when passed as a parameter in an extension method and what's an elegant solution to it?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, parameter-passing, ushort

I have this extension method:

```
public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
{
    return list.Contains(source);
}
```

Now I need to use the above method for a `ushort`. When I try

```
ushort p = 3;
if (p.In(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
   return;
```

The first line casts `3` to a `ushort` well. But when `3` is passed as a parameter, I get the error

> 'ushort' does not contain a definition for 'In' and the best extension method overload 'Extensions.In(T, params T[])' has some invalid arguments.

But this works:

```
ushort p = 3;
if (Extensions.In(p, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
   return;
```

which is weird.

1. Why does it work with the second example, but not the first?
2. What's a good alternative that would help me here? Since there are no literals for `short` or `ushort` I'm failing to find a simpler alternative than manually casting each integer like this:

   ```
   ushort p = 3;
   if (p.In((ushort)1, (ushort)2, (ushort)3, (ushort)4, (ushort)5))
      return;
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it work with second example, but not first?

First, let's work out what the compiler infers `T` to be.  Some parameters are `ushort` and some are `int`.  `ushort` has an implicit conversion to `int` and `int` does not have an implicit conversion to `ushort`, so `T` is `int`.

The key here is in section 7.6.5.2 of the C# 4 specification (emphasis mine):

> **An extension method Ci.Mj is eligible if:**
>
> - Ci is a non-generic, non-nested class
> - The name of Mj is identifier
> - Mj is accessible and applicable when applied to the arguments as a static method as shown above
> - **An implicit *identity, reference or boxing conversion* exists from expr to the type of the first parameter of Mj.**

There is an *implicit* conversion from `ushort` to `int`, but not an *identity, reference, or boxing* conversion!

So, the following are legal:

```
Extensions.In<ushort>(p, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Extensions.In<int>(p, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // implicit conversion allowed
Extensions.In(p, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // T is int
p.In<ushort>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

but the following are not:

```
p.In<int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // implicit conversion not allowed
p.In(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // T is int
```

Note that you can get the same error without generics if you define `In` as

```
public static bool In(this int source, params int[] list)
{
    return list.Contains(source);
}
```

Comment: Accepted! `An implicit identity, reference or boxing conversion exists from expr to the type of the first parameter of Mj.` gives the answer to this! Though I believe C# could be a lot smarter! :(

Answer (score 5):

Well, you define a generic function, so you have to define *the exact* type it has to deal with. Because if you give just numbers (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, etc.) to the function. They could be just **anything**: `short`, `ushort`, `integer`...

So you can do:

or

```
ushort p = 3;
if (p.In<ushort>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
   return;
```

Or like you did in your second example, cast every parameter to the desired type:

```
ushort p = 3;
if (p.In((ushort)1, (ushort)2, (ushort)3, (ushort)4, (ushort)5))
   return;
```

I, personally, would prefer the *first* case.

**EDIT**

What about why it works in this case:

```
ushort p = 3;
if (Extensions.In(p, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
   return;
```

is because you *explicitly* pass like a `this` (first parameter) the `p` which is a **known type** for compiler, so it *can* infer it.

The **default  type** for `1, 2, 3, 4, etc.` is `int`. So when you call

```
p.In(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

`T` is treated (or tends to be) like `integer` value. As a compiler **has no guarantee** that there would  not be any data lost (when you're using `ushort` on integer), it gives an error message. It forces you to explicitly define a *smaller type*.

Note that: function parameters are defined like `T[]`, so you pass integers (at least compiler thinks so) but pretending it to be `ushort` (as you're calling ext-method from `p`).

For a proof, try to run

```
int p = 3;
if (p.In(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
   return;
```

This works perfectly.

Comment: the first looks better, taken. Do you know about the first question of mine?

Comment: A better question is why it cannot infer that the type is ushort based on source?

Comment: @juharr exactly, but going the old way, it infers! only when extending the method, it doesnt!

Comment: @juharr: because the funcition is called for `T`. What is a `T` ? You have to specify it.

Comment: I would `guess` that the first parameter (the `this` one) fixes the generic type to be ushort. After that, `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` are treated as integers, that can't be auto-converted to ushort because of possible loss of precission. I guess we need Eric Lippert or Jon Skeet to answer this one.

Comment: @Tigran isn't that specified in the extension method approach too? isn't variable `p` already `ushort` when calling `p.In(...)` ? Your answer on my first question is incomplete unless you say what's the difference between the two approaches for the compiler. I rate it as a bug in extension method feature!

Comment: @Martijn then why does Extension.In(p,1,2,3,4,5) work?  Would love to see what Eric or Jon would say.

Comment: @Tigran, but p.In(1,2,3,4,5) is just syntactic sugar for Extention.In(p,1,2,3,4,5).  I guess it infers before it applies that?

Comment: @juharr: the numbers are threated like `integers` per default, so if you pass a type, like `ushort` compiler **has no guarantee** that there would be no any data lost. So comiler **forces** you define concrete *smaller* type, in this case. Everything is correct.

Comment: @nawfal: May be, but in that way it will let you jum easily in problems. The way MS tends to construct compiler is *guide* you throw correct process, and not do smart automatic inferences based on bilion possible variants can be found in the code.

Comment: @Tigran no, if data loss could be a problem, then it has to be in the second case too. How can compiler tell us that there is a potential pitfall in the first example alone? I think its about the order in which the parameters are inferred and in the first case the `params T[]` is first inferred I guess.